# Acyclic Manhattan turtle

Tags: graphs, formal-grammars

There is a grammar that describes the walks of a turtle around Manhattan, such that the turtle
always returns home. It is described in the book [*"Parsing Techniques"* by Dick Grune and Ceriel
J.H. Jacobs](https://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_2nd_Edition/), page 18. Unfortunately, I could not find a source online, but the rules are
rather simple:

$$ G = \left\langle \{0\}, \Sigma = \{N, S, E, W\}, R, 0 \right\rangle \\[2ex]
R = \left\{ \begin{align}
& 0 \to N 0 S    \\
& 0 \to E 0 W    \\
& 0 \to \epsilon \\[2ex]
& N S \to S N \\
& \dots \quad \scriptsize{(\text{11 other pairs of distinct } \sigma, \tau \in \Sigma)}
\end{align} \right.$$

I actually went ahead and generated some sentences of this grammar. Example:

$$ NENNEENSWWSWSS $$

*(Sentence № 10617)*

A sentence such as this one corresponds to a graph, like the following:

```
+-----------------+
|                 |
|                 |
|              *  |
|              ⭣  |
|      * ⭠ * ⭠ *  |
|      ⭣          |
|  * ⭠ *          |
|  ⭣   ⭡          |
|  * ⭢ *          |
|  ⭣              |
|  +              |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

*(Or, rather, to a path on the square lattice of Manhattan, but a path defines a subgraph.)*

As this example shows, the walk of our turtle will sometimes have loops.

**How hard would it be to compose a grammar that generates exactly the acyclic walks?**

**P.S.** As pointed out in comments, there will always be at least one cycle. Let us call that cycle *"trivial"* and say *"a grammar that generates exactly the walks with only the trivial cycle"* instead.

Comment: If the path starts and ends at the same point (by definition of the grammar), what do you mean by _acyclic_? If the turtle returns home won't it always be a cyclic path?

Comment: @ryan True. Let us say "not non-trivially cyclic" instead.